# Does Someone have the Deco Cover Drill Template of the iRobot Create 2?

Tags: irobot-create

I am developing a robot with the iRobot Create 2, and I need to built a structure over it, because of that I am looking for the Drilling Template to help me. I already looked in the oficial webpage and it isn´t there, though one of you might have it and could share it here.

Thanks!

Comment: google `Deco Cover Drill Template of the iRobot Create 2`  .... one of the hits has a link to the document ..... it is out of date so use `WaybackMachine` https://archive.org/web/web.php to retrieve the archived version

Answer (score 1):

From the main [iRobot STEM Create 2 Projects page](https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2/projects), there is a link to the [Create 2 Deco Cover Modification](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Deco_Cover_Modification.pdf). This link was accidentally broken while updating other content, but it's fixed, now.

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: There are also solid models, including one of a "brick-compatible" deco cover here: https://www.thingiverse.com/irobot/designs